# Виснет запрос к VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api

Всех, приветствую!

Есть код клиента:

> ```
> api.VK.api('getProfiles', { uids: viewer_id, fields:'photo_big' },
> ```
>
> onReceiveUsers, onReceiveError);
>
> ```
> public function onReceiveError(err:* = null):void
> {
>    _log.AddLog('Error');
> }
>
> public function onReceiveUsers(data:Array):void
> {
>    _log.AddLog("Good");
> }
> ```

Вот функция Init в iframe:

> ```
> VK.init(function()
> {
>
>   viewer_id       = getUrlParams("viewer_id");
>
>   var flashvars   = {
>       api_id:getUrlParams("api_id"),
>       ....
>   };
>   var params = {
>       menu: "false",
>       wmode: "transparent",
>       allowFullScreen: ...
>   };
>   var attributes = {
>       id: ....
>   };
>
>   swfobject.embedSWF("https://bottle.bigman.pro/main.swf",
> ```
>
> "Bigman", "807", "750", "10", null,
> flashvars, params, attributes);
>     });

Мы в любом случае должны получить либо good либо error. Проблема в том, что на запросе всё просто подвисает. Причем подвисает при получении json ответа (т.е. если вызывать post wall, сообщение на стене опубликуется, а вот на ответе повиснет).

Приложение iframe. Policyfile настроен, всё ок. Сертификат подписан, тоже всё нормально.
//vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2 используется, а не //vk.com/js/xd_connection.js?2.

Какие еще моменты есть? Может, есть какие-то еще мысли?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ещё вариант — что ВК тут проседал пару раз недавно. Может, просто попали на момент, когда api глючил? См. [аптайм тут](https://vk.com/dev/health).

Comment: Точно нет, пробовал менять туда и обратно https. Бага так же воспроизводилась. Похоже, вконтакт четко разделяет http, кто зашел, и https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, ошибка была в том, что нельзя пускать Адрес IFrame по https протоколу. Убрал. Сделал http. Все заработало. Видимо, баг ВКонтакта.  
http://cs623122.vk.me/v623122510/106d/YiSKUszCPsk.jpg
Хотя по существу разницы не должно быть, какой трафик где идет.

Comment: Разница есть. Если у вас iFrame загружен по https, он может отказаться загружать что-либо по незащищённому http. Вангую, что виснущий json полагается на настройки приложения: поле "Адрес IFRAME" должно содержать только **http**-адрес, а поле "HTTPS-адрес IFRAME" — только **https**.